# Reduce If in Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

How can I apply the reduce operation only if a predicate is true?

For example:

```
        Stream.of("foo=X","bar=Y","foo=Z")
        .reduce((arg1, arg2)-> arg1.contains(arg2) ? arg1  : <reduceNothing>)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to get rid of one of `"foo=..."` to have at the end a list of `"foo=X","bar=Y"`

Comment: can you add the `args` content please?

Comment: how about a concrete example? say you have a `List<List<Integer>>`...

Comment: besides, a `reduce` needs to return a new instance all the time, so simply `? arg1` is wrong anyway; plz provide what you actually want to do

Comment: `reduce` return single value. What result you expecting?

Comment: are you sure this is the correct edit? I think we still need details, like what is the expected output?

Comment: you can add a filter before the reduce part in your sample code.

Comment: and of course `reduce` and after a `collect` = two terminal operations... voting to close as unclear for now; may be provide some clear details

Comment: @Eugene it says the expected output

Comment: let me get this straight, what you mean is that if you have already seen `foo` *before*, ignore the current mapping where `foo` is found and so on? Or simpler you want to get rid of duplicates, where some part of the string is present? for example: `"foo=X","bar=Y","foo=Z", "bar=M", "test=12", "test=45"`, your result would be: `"foo=X","bar=Y", "test=12"`?

Comment: @Eugene yes exactly!!!

Comment: @Eugene I will test the answers carefully. When done, will accept the one that solves my problem in the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it (without streams):

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

yourListOfArgs.forEach(arg -> map.merge(arg.split("=")[0], arg, (o, n) -> o));

Collection<String> uniqueArgs = map.values();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a merger that would get the first (in encounter order) result in case a duplicate is found:

```
Collection<String> result = Stream.of("foo=X", "bar=Y", "foo=Z", "bar=M", "test=12")
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    x -> x.split("=")[0],
                    Function.identity(),
                    (left, right) -> left,
                    LinkedHashMap::new))
            .values();

    System.out.println(result); // [foo=X, bar=Y, test=12]
```

I've used `LinkedHashMap` in case you need to preserve the initial order, if you don't need that, simply use:

```
 Collection<String> result = Stream.of("foo=X", "bar=Y", "foo=Z", "bar=M", "test=12")
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    x -> x.split("=")[0],
                    Function.identity(),
                    (left, right) -> left))
            .values();

  System.out.println(result); // [bar=Y, test=12, foo=X]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Stream.of("foo=X","bar=Y","foo=Z")
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    x -> getLeftSide(x),
                    x -> x,
                    (x, y) -> x
            ))
            .values();
```

I assume that you have `getLeftSide` method that returns left part of assignment (convert `"foo=bar"` to `"foo"`).

Answer (score 1):

If there is flexibility to use any other operation other than reduce then following could be answer:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    System.out.println(methodContainingFilteringLogic(word -> word.equals("foo=Z"),
            Stream.of("foo=X","bar=Y","foo=Z")));
}

public static List<String> methodContainingFilteringLogic(Predicate<String> predicate, Stream<String> wordsStream) {
    return wordsStream.filter(word -> predicate.negate().test(word))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In your case, it would be known at point on which basis given stream should be filtered. At that point `methodContainingFilteringLogic` could be invoked.

Comment: with this solution I have to hardcode ```"foo=Z"``` so it's not valid as I will not know the value of Z and if I put  ```"foo=Z"``` every  ```"foo=..."```  will be removed

Comment: Hard coding could be eliminated by passing Predicate as an argument.

Comment: response is updated. I am not sure this is what you were looking for.